# Printing in Firefox last portion of long image is skipped

Tags: jquery, firefox, printing, printthis

I'm working in [printThis.js](https://github.com/jasonday/printThis). In IE and Chrome printing is working fine but in Firefox image bottom portion in printing is cutoff. What am I missing? See [this JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skhurams/u6pt1jv2/)

Here is what I have done so far

```
 $(document).ready(function () { //fire on DOM ready            

     $('#dvPrint').click(function () {
         $('#comparisonImage').printThis({
             pageTitle: "Site Comparison",
             importCSS: true,
             debug: true,
             printMode: 'popup'
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: Hi, I am the author of the printThis plugin. Do you have a screenshot of what is happening in firefox? Also, 'printMode' is not an option in my plugin - what is that for?

Comment: If you notice, it is printing just the first two parts of the each image. The layout is not being preserved; this may be an issue of being a jsfiddle - it's not bringing in the css from the parent page. You should try and create an html file, upload to drop box, and share the link with me.

Comment: i have created an html file but still not working i when i click print button i print it in windows xps document  viewer here the link to working copy of html file https://www.dropbox.com/s/qv6w1aomu1cc2h7/printThis-master.zip?dl=0
</br> while in chrome and ie its working

Comment: im comparing two images and i want the user to print the comparison

Comment: if IE and chrome 100% image is printed and in firefox 50% image is printed for eg i have image which has 3 pages in print priview only one page is printed through firefox

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look (holidays), but will look this weekend. I think it will likely be resolved with CSS.